# Strange Input behavior since updated on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, input-devices

I have problems with my Mouse and my keyboard.
It worked perfectly before I upgraded to **17.10**.

My first problem

I can't move my mouse when I have pressed a key two seconds ago. I know that there is a option called

> Disable Touchpad while Typing

but it seems to not be in Ubuntu 17.10.

My second problem

There is area were I can't **scroll/click** with my mouse. The unclickable area seems to appear randomly and will stay. When I restart my pc the area is moved to a random position.

I am using an **Lenovo Thinkpad T420** (I switched the hard drive but I don't think the hard drive courses this).

`Uname -a` returns this.

```
Linux david-thinkpad 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```